# Anchore engine image scanning - how to skip certain feeds?

Tags: docker, security, jenkins, docker-compose, jenkins-plugins

I want to scan my docker image against only certain feeds pulled by anchore engine and not all( for e.g I want to skip NVD feed) . How can I do this?

TIA!

Answer (score 0):

In the configuration yaml file, there is an option to selectively enable certain feeds.

In the `config.yaml` file:

```
feeds:
  selective_sync:
    enabled: True
    feeds:
      vulnerabilities: true
      packages: false
      nvdv2: false
```